# How to change the class with main method in VS for mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac

In VS for windows when we right click in the project there is a property option available to change the start up object (list of classes with main methods). However, I could not find it in VS for Mac. I use VS for mac. How to do the same in VS for mac?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Solution window, right click the project and select Options.
2. In the Project Options window select Build - General.
3. Enter the name of your startup class in the `Main Class` section and click OK.

[image: Project Options - Main Class]